# Cycling through Json objects

Tags: c#, json, win-universal-app

Fairly new to working with Json and having troubles

```
[{"page":1,"example":  

  [{"number":6666666,"Year":2005}]},    

  {"page":2,"example":      

  [{"number":555555,"Year":2000}]}]
```

This is my Json, it's just an example and not actually Json that i'm using but set out the same way

I been using the following c# to get the values within page 1 of the Json but i need help getting the values from page 2 and so forth

```
   var http = new HttpClient();
   var response = await http.GetAsync("Example.json");
   var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   List<Rootobject> RootList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(result);
   foreach (Rootobject item in RootList)
   {
    listBox1.Items.Add(item.Example[0].number.ToString());
   }
```

Lastly my Classes are

```
  public class Thread
    {
        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public int number { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("year")]
        public int year { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rootobject
    {
        [JsonProperty("page")]
        public int page { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("example")]
        public List<Example> example{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by saying you need values for page 2 and so forth? As I can understand your code, it puts into ListBox the values of first example for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ expression

```
var data = var i in RootList
           where i.page == 2; // here you can replace the number as per your requirement
```

Method to return required data

```
Public Rootobject GetDataByPage(int pageNo) {
      return RootList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.page == pageNo);
}
```

Comment: do you mean        
           var data = from i in RootList
                            where i.page == 2
                            select i;

Comment: Yes. Any problems with that?